# Alternative to background-image in emailing?

Tags: html, css, email

I'm trying to transform the following example into a version compatible with mobile devices email client apps (Gmail, Yahoo, etc.).

[image]

Putting a background image to a table and then putting 2 images works correctly on webmail clients, but not all mobile devices display the background image.

Is there any way to get this same result without using background-image?

Using `<img>` appears to be the only way to make the email responsive and all devices display it correctly.

Comment: You should create a big table wrapper and set the background image there with inline css. Checkout [this post on mailchimp](https://blog.mailchimp.com/background-images-and-css-in-html-email/) for more info. Note; unfortunately you'll have to forget everything about proper html/css when building css templates ;) Pretend you're back in the 90's and building websites with tables and inline css :)

Comment: Already tried that :(, on Gmail app in Android 4.4.2 the background-image is displayed correctly like on the web, but on Gmail app in Android 7.0 only the bgcolor is displayed.

Comment: Even trying an official theme in MailChimp that contains background images (suposed to be correctly coded)... the background image is not displayed on some mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Why not place a background image in a container div instead of the actual table?.  This will make it pretty much universally compatible.  While outlook mail doesn't support divs with certain CSS styling, if you are using a static background container div, you shouldn't run into any problems.

[article on issue](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/05/div-tags-in-html-email-newsletters/)

Comment: I've read somewhere that `divs` are not supported in Outlook, the safe way to make emails is with static content made with `tables`. Want to avoid the use of `divs`.

Comment: True that they can be a hassle sometimes, but in many instances they may still solve your problem.  You probably should avoid them if you are using multiple columns... however it sounds like you simply want one  background container, without any position or float styling.  [Maybe div will work](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/05/div-tags-in-html-email-newsletters/)

Comment: After testing a bit... putting the background on a div works on the same devices it was working before, but on others devices the background image still not displays. Will check other ways to achieve it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmm strange, let us know when you figure it out.